# Running a javascript function on page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've got a javascript function in ASP.Net called timer().  In the code-behind, I've got an

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

and inside of that I've got a function that fires this line:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel4, this.GetType(), "timerscript", "timer()", true);
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft JScript Runtime Error: 'timer' is undefined
```

When I look at the code, it looks like the site.master has loaded, but nothing on the page I'm actually loading has loaded yet.

I tried putting my timer code on site.master, but it references a specific field on the page I've got the timer on, and it won't load.

Here is my timer script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    /* Stop, Clear and Pause the timer displayed under the pause buttons  */
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
        start = document.getElementById('start'),
        stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
        clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
        seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
        t;

    function add() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('<%=h1.ClientID%>').innerText = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);;
        timer();
    }
    function timer() {
        t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
    }

    function stp() {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }

    function clr() {
        document.getElementById('<%=h1.ClientID%>').innerText = "00:00:00";
        seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;  
    }
</script>
```

So, can anyone either a) tell me how to get this script to run when I load my page, or b) tell me how to edit this script so it will run off site.master?

I should add that the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock line works fine in all other places where it's firing after the page has loaded, so I know it works.  The only place it doesn't work is on the initial page load.

Comment: My guess is you want RegisterStartupScript instead.

Comment: Have you tried just placing your js load in the shared layout.cshtml view and then calling it there?

Comment: If you want to call the js function when the page loads, then why are you not calling it after you declare the function in the same JS snippet? Ej function timer(){ alert('hola'); } timer(); ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to epascarello's suggestion, I finally got this working:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel4, UpdatePanel4.GetType(), "timerscript", "timer();", true);
```

One thing to note (which drove me nuts); you **need** to have a semicolon following your script name when you use this, whereas I did not need to have one when using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock.  Without that semicolon, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with client script, try the methods under Page.ClientScript

for example:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
```